# PHP ping script does not work after Apache restart in Centos

Tags: php, apache, ping

My PHP ping script works fine before Apache restart but after restart it does not work.

It shows

```
Array(
       )
```

My PHP script is

```
<?php
function pingAddress($ip) {
 exec('$ping -c 4 $ip', $outcome, $status);    
 print_r($outcome);
}
if(isset($_POST['ip'])){
 pingAddress($_POST['ip']);
}
?>
```

Comment: Check your firewall rules, may be ping service disabled.

Comment: @Kamal Thanks. I'm new to linux server can you explain me more in detail?

Comment: I used to work with plesk panel with Centos so I am not sure about row server how it can be enabled but in plesk panel under tools, you can find firewall rules.

Answer (score 0):

The value of $ip can't be passed within simple quotes (regardless of wether or not you restart apache)

You should have a better chance with this: 
exec("ping -c 4 $ip", $outcome, $status);

Comment: Thanks Nick. But I already tried with this, still outputs empty array().